# logging the console to file in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I am creating an electron application to run on my desktop. Since i wont be running it from the console I want to swap the standard `console` for a nodejs writestream to write it to a file. I was able to come up with this

```
var logStream=fs.createWriteStream("log.txt",{flags:"a+"});
console.log(logStream);
logStream.write(new Date().toString() +"\r");
console=new console.Console({stdout:logStream,stderr:logStream});
```

This is where things get weird when the code runs perfectly fine when running in node. In electron however it gives the error `TypeError: Console expects a writable stream instance` but the `logStream.write(new Date().toString() +"\r");` runs just fine so obviously it is a writable stream instance. Is this just an electron glitch or is there a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you found since but,
on reading this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21366

Try to replace `console=new console.Console({stdout:logStream,stderr:logStream});` by `console=new console.Console(logStream,logStream);`